# How to install QGIS 2.0 on Mint 15?

Tags: qgis, python

Trying to use QGIS 2.0 on Mint 15 (based on Ubuntu 13)

I installed, uninstalled and re-installed QGIS from various repositories (ubuntugis-unstable, then qgis.org/debian raring - not clear for me which one I should use). I don't seem to have any python support. Any help appreciated!

If I try

```
apt-get install python-qgis
```

I get the message that

```
the packages libgdal1 libqgis2.0.1 qgis qgis-providers 
are going to be uninstalled
```

Bump:
Still no solution. I uninstalled QGIS and `apt-get autoremove`, kept only ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable. Now when I try

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

the error message is

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 python-qgis : Dépend: python-qgis-common (= 2.0.1-2+raring1) mais ne sera pas installé
 qgis-plugin-grass : Dépend: grass642
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

Can someone help?

Comment: check the http://qgis.org/debian/dists/raring/main/ and http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But which one of the two should I use? And should I first disable the repository I have used before (http://qgis.org/debian raring main)? Should I uninstall QGIS and then re-install it?

Comment: I had a similar problem 2 years ago with QGIS 1.7, which I solved by downgrading my PyQT4 library. The library had been updated and became incompatible with python-qgis. Link to my original error message and solution, in case that helps: http://northwestspatial.com/wp/?p=302

Comment: @Alice check the dates on both 24th September 2013. Would try the qgis.org first.

Comment: Mapperz thank you but I don't understand much. Should I add deb qgis.org/debian/dists/raring/main in the file source.list?

Comment: @L_Holcombe, I guess it is a problem of that sort, but how could I know which library is the one that causes the problem?

Comment: You could try launching QGIS from the terminal - it may offer you a useful warning or error message that is suppressed when you launch from the desktop.

Comment: I start wondering if there is any usable qgis version for Ubuntu etc. available at the moment. Removed qgis-dev, cause processing is broken ... now the stable version has no python support resulting in no plugins at all ... gnrrr

Comment: I'm happy I am not the only one having this problem. @L_Holcombe, I get no error message launching QGIS with the terminal, since it is working properly, I just don't have python support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this is what finally worked though I'm not sure why (using aptitude instead of apt-get? It seems that aptitude manages better the dependencies).

First I cleaned a little (not sure it's useful)

```
sudo apt-get purge qgis python-qgis

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and suppressed the qgis.org/debian repository from sources.list

Then

```
sudo aptitude install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude install qgis python-qgis
```

QGIS works now WITH vector tools and python support.
Thanks to http://blog.m0le.net/2013/10/01/installer-qgis-2-0-sur-mint/

Comment: Now in 2014 you should add stable ubuntu repo instead of unstable, so `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` should be `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa`